# HQL to SQL: Querying an Oracle database in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql, oracle, netbeans, hql

I'm new to Hibernate and I'm having difficulty generating a very basic SQL statement from HQL.

I followed [this](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html) tutorial pretty much to the letter with the exception that the database I connect to is Oracle 10g rather than MySql and the schema is different.

In the tutorial the HQL statement:
`from Actor`
creates SQL
`select actor0_.actor_id as col_0_0_ from actor actor0_`

My HQL statement:
`from Emp`
creates SQL
`select emp0_.EMPNO as col_0_0_ from USER.EMP emp0_`

This returns a "...java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00903: invalid table name" when I try to run it.

If however, I manually modify the SQL statement and remove "USER.", the statement runs fine.
`select emp0_.EMPNO as col_0_0_ from EMP emp0_`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Note: In the tutorial it says it should create the statement
"...sakila.actor actor0_" but the screenshot shows just "...actor actor0_"

Regards,
Brian

Answer (score 2):

At this step in the tutorial:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html#03a

Did you change the dialect you enter to `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`?

Comment: I changed it from OracleDialect to Oracle10gDialect, cheers! But I cleaned and rebuilt the proj and the same thing is happening.